# Twitter Bootstrap - Position issue with row-fluid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently building a website using Twitter bootstrap (which is amazing!). 
I had the layout using:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
```

Which works great, I have 2 divs per row basically, and we didn't have to include a counter in our loop to get rid of the margins. It was perfect! But we decided to change our mind about having a fixed layout, so I switched from the .row to .row-fluid. And this is when the problem comes.

I know have something like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
```

**And the div's with .span6 work well for the first row, but then the margin-left on the .span6 are showing up starting from the second row**, therefore the layout is, well, ...not good.

I'm **surprised it works amazing for fixed layout but not row-fluid**. Is there a work-around for this?  I used this on all my site, so having to add counters for all of them would...too much work.

Here is JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/denislexic/uAs6k/3/

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: a http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net example would be an improvement to help you!

Comment: Thanks, I added one: http://jsfiddle.net/denislexic/uAs6k/3/

Comment: A working version http://jsfiddle.net/uAs6k/4/ . A margin-left:0; and a clear was added.

Comment: @luke2012 - Thanks, but I still need the padding between the 2 spans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know the number of span for each row, you can use an expression like this:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:nth-child(3n+1) {
   margin-left: 0;
}
```

for example: if you have 3 spans for each row, the above expression will removes margin from the first span of each row. And the below one removes the margin-right for the last element on each row:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 32):

Your 2 examples actually have 4 `<div class="span6"></div>` within a full-width 'row'... adding up to '24', or twice the width meant for a 'row' or 'row-fluid', based on the 12 column grid setup. You're basically creating dropping floats when there are too many to fit within the parent row's width.
(*This is also why it seems that 'margin-left:0' is not being applied to your 3rd 'span6', which **looks** like it's the first 'span6' of a 2nd row.*)

**In a default/fixed 'row'**, the nested column's 'span*'s + 'offset*'s will need to be less than or equal to its parent's column 'span*', OR if it's a first-level row, then 12, because the floated 'span*' widths are in pixels.

**In a flexible/fluid 'row-fluid'**, the column widths are set by percentage, so each row and nested row can have nested column 'span*'s and 'offset*'s that add up to 12, each time.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

This should solve your issue with the 'row-fluid' setup.
http://jsfiddle.net/csabatino/uAs6k/9/

```html
<h1>NOW this is working.</h1>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">Content</div>
    <div class="span6">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">Content</div>
    <div class="span6">Content</div>
</div>


<h1>Default fixed 'row' is working, too.</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">Content</div>
    <div class="span6">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">Content</div>
    <div class="span6">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve it when using it on LI elements with span?

Answer (score 3):

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
margin-left: 0;
}
```

It only removes margin for the first child so you will need to add another class or change `span6` to have `margin-left:0;`

Comment: But is there a solution? Why does it not do it like the .row?  Thanks.

Comment: the fluid css is different from the fixed. It's just how they have done it. On line 543 of the bootstrap.css you can edit .row-fluid [class*="span"] to have a margin-left:0;

Comment: Having the margin already specified will make sure the fluid layout is using 100% of the browser window.

Comment: a better solution is to split them up into different rows

Comment: adding maring-left:0 to .row-fluid .span6 { was workfing for me !

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by putting an empty div with span12 at the begining, uggly in the code but effective in the gui

Answer (score 0):

If the app can't count elements and divide into rows, removing `margin-left` and adding `padding-right` worked just fine for me:

```
.gal [class*="span"] {margin-left:0; padding-right:20px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uAs6k/116/

Answer (score 0):

I just did this with jQuery instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function doFluidFirstSpan() {
        var top = $('.thumbnails > li:first-child').position().top;
        $('.thumbnails > li').each(function(){
            if($(this).position().top > top) {
                $(this).addClass("alpha");
                top = $(this).position().top;   
            }
        }); 
    }

    doFluidFirstSpan();
}
```

and the css:

```
.alpha { margin-left: 0 !important; }
```

Comment: naturally then you need to call the function :/